# Handle (skip) UnauthorizedAccessException in EnumerateFiles() LINQ C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, search

I am trying to write a high performance file system searcher that can search unindexed drives (both local and network) very fast filtering on extensions and keywords. I am trying to achieve this using C#'s `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories()`, `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()` and LINQ queries. From my testing, this is (by far) the best performing code I could find:

```
FileInfo[] dirFiles = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
                            .AsParallel()
                            .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                                .Where(fi => EndsWithExtension(fi.Extension)) )
                                                .ToArray();
```

However, the `UnauthorizedAccessException` is not handled and when thrown, crashes the entire query.

I've tried various ways as outlined on SO related to this issue, but I found that they are significantly slower in search performance. This second best method I found working is over 20 times slower for example:

```
try {
    foreach (string fileName in EnumerateFiles(dirInfo, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
        if (ContainsKeyword(fileName)) {
             Results.Add(fileName.FullName);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) { continue; }
```

I would like to skip over the directory when it throws an exception. I've being trying to achieve this with something similar to this, but I can't get it to work (my knowledge of LINQ and Enumerables is too limited...):

```
FileInfo[] dirFiles = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
                            .AsParallel()
                            .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                                .SkipExceptions()
                                                .Where(fi => EndsWithExtension(fi.Extension)) )
                                                .ToArray();

public static class Extensions {
        public static IEnumerable<T> SkipExceptions<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values) {
            using (var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator()) {
                bool next = true;
                while (next) {
                    try {
                        if (enumerator.Current != null)
                            Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.ToString()); 
                        next = enumerator.MoveNext();
                    } catch {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (next) yield return enumerator.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to handle (`UnauthorizedAccess`) exceptions, while still remaining as high performant as the "raw" LINQ query?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Answer EDITED:
A workaround is to call it recursively instead of using SearchOption.AllDirectories. This is actually more inefficient in your case because you don't need to load every file in the filesystem into an array. Start with the following helper methods:

```
    List<string> GetDirectoriesRecursive (string parent)
    {
        var directories = new List<string>();
        GetDirectoriesRecursive (directories, parent);
        return directories;
    }

    void GetDirectoriesRecursive (List<string> directories, string parent)
    {
        directories.Add (parent);
        foreach (string child in GetAuthorizedDirectories (parent))
            GetDirectoriesRecursive (directories, child);
    }

    string[] GetAuthorizedDirectories (string dir)
    {
        try { return Directory.GetDirectories (dir); }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { return new string[0]; }
    }

    string[] GetAuthorizedFiles (string dir)
    {
        try { return Directory.GetFiles (dir); }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { return new string[0]; }
    }
```

Then, to get the big files:

```
     var bigFiles =
         from dir in GetDirectoriesRecursive ( @"c:\" )
         from file in GetAuthorizedFiles (dir)
         where new FileInfo (file).Length > 100000000 
         select file;
```

Or, to get just their directories:

```
     var foldersWithBigFiles =
         from dir in GetDirectoriesRecursive ( @"c:\" )
         where GetAuthorizedFiles (dir).Any (f => new FileInfo (f).Length > 100000000 )
         select dir;
```

ANOTHER APPROACH:

```
 string[] directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"\\testnetwork\abc$","*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Catch(typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException)).ToArray();
```

ADDED missing part:

```
static class ExceptionExtensions
{
public static IEnumerable<TIn> Catch<TIn>(
            this IEnumerable<TIn> source,
            Type exceptionType)
{   
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    while (true)
    {
        var ok = false;

        try
        {
            ok = e.MoveNext();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.GetType() != exceptionType)
                throw;
            continue;
        }

        if (!ok)
            yield break;

        yield return e.Current;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a poorly described answer whether the link may contain the solution. You should elaborate at least some part of the link in your answer.

Comment: changed my vote upon your edit. Thanks for the answer. happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not a solution to my issue. The first suggestion with the various helper methods has a lot of overhead (will convert Strings of filepaths to FileInfo objects, build up large amounts of memory with the recursion). This slows the query down significantly. The later is indeed more elegant. I have seen this solution (you forgot to copy in the most important part though: the ExceptionExtension), but I could not get this to work. It still throws  UnauthorizedAccessExceptions.